# Best Practice and Understanding any keyword in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a Pipe to filter data. Most of the times I have used datatype `any`, which means it could be `any type`. I have following questions regarding this:

- Is it a Good Practice?
- Does it affect the **performance** if we handle **Large Data**?
- Does it make any difference in **Application Data** (size of the initialized variable)?

For example, I have this Pipe

```
import {Pipe , PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name:'textFilter'
})
export class TextFilter implements PipeTransform{

transform(data:any,term:any):any{


     if(term===undefined) return data;
     return data.filter(function (da:any) {    
     return da.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());

     }) 

}

}
```

Here I have used `any` to avoid datatype **mismatch**. So is it the right way?

Comment: @estus This is most common doubt where everyone is getting while developing Angular2 Applications , If it is wrong please correct it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- No it's not a good practice. Types are there to help you and your fellow programmers. If you don't need them, use plain js or ES6/7/Whatever
- Types have no performance impact, types are completely erased at runtime.
- Doesn't matter in terms of compiled output size. Also has no impact on memory, since what actually runs is plain js.

Comment: Plain js means , Are u talking about Javascript var ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Javascript var"? You have the option to compile it from es3-es6. Just take a look at the compiled output and see it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification